# Trying to close multiple stream with finally

Tags: java, file, file-io, try-catch-finally

I have a program that open 3 streams of data but I do not know how to close all of them, here it is the closing part of the program.

```
finally {//cerrando muestras
        try{
            if(muestras!=null){
                muestras.close();
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {//cerrando salida
        try{
            if(salida!=null){
                salida.close();
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose that it is because I can not do that nested finally but I do not know any other method, thank you for your time.

Comment: If you use Java 7+ you can use a try-with resources on multiple streams and get rid of the finally block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statements introduced in Java 7 rather than closing your streams on your own. Consider the following as an example :

```
try (
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(out))
) {
    bufferedWriter.write(text);
} catch(IOException e) {
    //log or propagate to the caller
}
```

Observe how you don't have to close the `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` streams manually.

Comment: Note that this is Java 7+ only.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue Since Java 6 has reached EOL and Java 8 is already out, explicitly mentioning that this works only for Java 7 is not really required. You don't see anyone mentioning that a piece of code will only work for Java 5. I am editing my post to add this info though.

Comment: Can I use this with  Objects? I mean, "salida" is an ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Well unfortunately entreprises aren't that fast on upgrading and a lot of my clients (Including big aerospatial industries) work with Java 6 or less. I think it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java6 or lower you could use a *wrapper* for you `close()`.

```
public void closeStreams(Closeable c){
  try{
    c.close();
   }
   catch(IOException e){
   }

  finally{
  // well noting here now..
  }
}
```

And you can use :

```
finally {//cerrando muestras
            if(muestras!=null){
                muestras.closeStreams();
            }

            if(salida!=null){
                salida.closeStreams();
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually end up making a utility method to do this sort of thing.

```
Stream muestras;
Stream salida;
...
finally {
        closeAll( muestras, salida );
    }


public class IoUtils
{

   private IoUtils() {}

   public static void closeAll( Closeable ... cls ) {
      for( Closeable c : cls ) {
         if( c != null )  try {
            c.close();
         } catch( IOException ex ) {
            Logger.getLogger( IoUtils.class.getName() ).
                    log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
         }
      }
   }
 }
```